# Is Substitution for Propositional Logic a purely syntactical process?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Would it be correct to say that $ (P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow (Q \wedge P)) $ is **not** a substitution instance of $ P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$?

Comment: It seems like it *is* a substitution instance: substitute $P\wedge Q$ for $P$ and $P$ for $Q$. (Separately, I don't understand how the title question relates to the body question: what does syntax vs. semantics have to do with whether one thing is a substitution instance of another?)

Comment: Well the problem is that you’ve substituted for $P$ in one instance with $P\land Q$ and the other $Q\land P.$ So it isn’t a pure substitution.

Comment: @NoahSchweber In the sense that the second occurrence of P is substituted for $ (Q \wedge P) $. Indeed $ P \wedge Q \equiv Q \wedge P $, but $ P \wedge Q $ and $ Q \wedge P $ are still different syntactically.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, I believe this 'substitution' to be incorrect. Could you clarify what you mean by 'pure'? My understanding of substitution is that it either is or is not a substitution.

Comment: @0implies0 Ohhhh, I see - I missed that difference! That's a great point, and you'd be right: a substitution instance has to be *literally* a substitution instance.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, I should of probably highlighted the difference with coloured text. All though I am not sure if that is considered bad form on Math SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is **not** a substitution instance: both $$(P\wedge Q)\rightarrow (P\rightarrow (P\wedge Q))\quad(\mbox{via }P\leadsto Q\wedge P, Q\leadsto P)$$ and $$(Q\wedge P)\rightarrow (P\rightarrow (Q\wedge P))\quad(\mbox{via }P\leadsto P\wedge Q, Q\leadsto P)$$ would be, but what you've written isn't since it "equivocates" between $P\leadsto Q\wedge P$ and $P\leadsto P\wedge Q$.

---

That said, we can modify the notion of "substitution instance" a bit to accommodate the example in the OP. Specifically, for a deduction relation $\vdash$ and a set of sentences $T$ we can talk about **substitution instances modulo $\vdash$ and $T$**: here we allow modifications of substitutions by $T\vdash$-equivalence. Specifically, a substitution instance of a sentence $\varphi$ is a sentence $\psi$ gotten from $\varphi$ by replacing the $i$th instance in $\varphi$ of a propositional variable $P$ with some formula $\theta_{i,P}$ such that we always have $T\vdash\theta_{i,P}\leftrightarrow\theta_{j,P}$.

So the OP would in this way be a substitution instance modulo the usual deduction relation for classical logic and the empty theory; on the other hand, "pure" substition corresponds to substitution modulo the empty deduction relation and the empty theory. I'm not sure if this is an actually useful notion to consider, but it's a natural generalization so it's worth noting.